# Setter on text only called after edit on Android, live on iOS

Tags: binding, mvvmcross

When I'm binding text to an input on iOS, my setter is called each time a character is added, on iOS, but not on Android.

If I put a breakpoint on a property that is binded to a TextField in iOS, each time a character is entered, the property setter will be called, but not on an Android EditText.

It makes more complex ViewModels with several input attached to getter/setter tested on iOS completely useless on Android since it cannot be used.

Is there a way to make the "MvxBind="Text SomeProperty" acting like iOS on Android?

Events like "AfterTextChanged" (any binding to a command) aren't property-friendly, and would  break my ViewModel. I don't want to have a platform-dependent workaround.

[Edit]

```
// Droid. It calls the TotalAmount setter once the editing is done.
<EditText local:MvxBind="Text TotalAmount,
 Mode=OneWayToSource; Text TotalAmountString, Mode=OneWay" />

// Touch. It calls the TotalAmount setter on key press.
set.Bind(MyTotalAmountTextField)
.For(v => v.Text)
.To(vm => vm.TotalAmount).OneWayToSource();

set.Bind(MyTotalAmountTextField)
.For(v => v.Text)
.To(vm => vm.TotalAmountString).OneWay();
```

By the way, the displayed property is always formatted with a dollar sign, that's why I'm using an half-duplex approach for binding.

Appart from this live (iOS) versus after-edit (Droid) problem, the bindings are working well.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the code you are using to bind on ios and on android? (the default binding normally works the same way on both)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour for `TwoWay` `Text` binding on both Android and iOS is to do per character binding.

You can see this behaviour in, for example, the N=0 video at 18:43 - http://youtu.be/_DHDMNB_IeY?t=18m43s

If you are not seeing this behaviour in your `EditText` then I guess it might be down in some way to your app or perhaps to a bug (e.g. perhaps in `OneWayToSource` binding somehow - this certainly isn't as commonly used as other binding modes).

To workaround this, I can only think to suggest:

1. Log it as an issue with a reproducible case (github repo) on GitHub/MvvmCross - someone there might be able to help - or you might be able to fix it yourself.
2. Try `TwoWay` binding instead
3. Try creating your own custom binding or your own custom control - this is actually very easy to do - see the tutorials N=28 and n=18 on http://mvvmcross.blogspot.com - for example you could try inheriting from EditText to create something like;

   ```
   public class MyEditText : EditText {
      public MyEditText(Context c, IAttributeSet a) {
          this.AfterTextChanged += (s,e) => MyTextChanged.Raise(this);
      }

      public event EventHandler MyTextChanged;
      public string MyText {
         get { return Text; }
         set { Text = value; }
      }
   }
   ```